# Qt, draw ontop of label with image as background

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

Im working on a app where i have an image shown in a `QLabel`.

```
setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage( image ) );
```

I would like to draw masks ontop of the image and save it to a file. Thinking basic drawing tools like circle, polygon, rectangle. Im not sure how i would solve this? Should i make a widget that have members for setbackground, and implement some click catch events to set points and handle it all in the paint event?

Any suggestions are welcome.

The goal are to make masks for a set of images to train some image processing systems from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be doing anything remotely graphically complex like what you describe, you're going to need to do it with QPainter or QGraphicsView.